# How can I use a toggle switch as a momentary switch on my arduino?

Tags: keyboard, arduino, togglebutton

I have a specific switch I need to use and it just happens to be toggle. Problem is, I need to send a keyboard stroke to my computer any time the button is pushed on or off. I tried one modification of the basic example on the Arduino website, but it isn't working for me:

```
const int buttonPin = 2;  // the number of the pushbutton pin
int prior = 0; 
int buttonState = 0;      // variable for reading the pushbutton status

void setup()
{
    pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT);
    Keyboard.begin();
}

void loop() 
{
    prior = buttonState;  
    buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin);
    if (buttonState != prior) {   
        Keyboard.write(32);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your exact issue? If you push it a lot does it work sometimes? If so you might  only need a pull down resistor.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can debug this issue by breaking into two part. First debug whether you are able to toggle of switch which you can do by switch led on/off whenever you toggle your switch (assuming your leds are working fine) in loop. 
Once this is done. Debug your Keyboard.Write() by just send some characters to pc at fixed delay may be 1sec in the loop. 
If both are working fine then you above program might work. Try adding some delay after keyboard.write().